# The modal attribute in the Dialog component of PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces

There is an attribute named `modal` in `Dialog` component of PrimeFaces. Checking the user guide, it just says it controls the modality of the component. But I just don't get it and want to know what it actually means.

Comment: @Ovoxo: no, that is what a dialog is. Read the answer about what adding 'modal' to a dialog adds to the behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modal = True means that the dialog is displayed in the foreground and nothing in the background is clickable.  You MUST take action on the dialog to dismiss it to continue using the page in the background.  A Non-modal dialog obviously lets the user interact with the page behind the dialog while the dialog is displayed.